# Is there a way to expand an array by repeating elements in both dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, resize, dimension

I am trying to resize an array to a larger size in Python by repeating each element proportionally to the new size.

So far, I was converting the array to an image and resize it accordingly, then convert it to an array again. However, it seems that I cannot convert all types of data to image so I need a general way to do this.

What I actually want is, lets have an array of size (2,2) and I want to resize it to a (4,4) array. i.e, I want to have an output array like in this example:

```
import numpy as np
input_array=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
outcome_array=np.array([[1,1,2,2],[1,1,2,2],[3,3,4,4],[3,3,4,4]])
```

I know it can be done by repeating but it only works if the size of output array is integer multiples of input array size. Image resizing tools do that resizing with a little loss in those cases, I am looking for a way to do that without using image tools.

Comment: `input_array.repeat(2, axis=0).repeat(2, axis=1)`

Comment: If the output size is integer multiples of input size, this works. But if output would be (5,5), how would I do that? I know I cannot do it very precisely but types of image resizing tools make it with a little information loss.

Comment: I would repeat to the nearest number of repetitions, and then just slice the array, e.g. `input_array.repeat(3, axis=0).repeat(3, axis=1)[:-1, :-1]` to get a 5x5 array. If you post a new question to ask about these cases when you can't *just* repeat the dimensions, I can try to provide a more general answer!

Comment: I asked it as a question in here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57177262/how-to-upsample-an-array-to-arbitrary-sizes?noredirect=1#comment100866908_57177262)