# How to upsample an array to arbitrary sizes?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, resize

I am trying to resize an array to a larger size in Python by repeating each element proportionally to the new size. However, I want to be able to resize to arbitrary sizes.

I know that I can do it with `numpy.repeat` if for example I have to double the size but lets say I want to convert an array of size `(180,150)` to `(300,250)`. I know there is not a perfect way to do this but I am looking for the most efficient (minimum loss of information) method!

So far, I was converting the array to an image and resize it accordingly, then convert it to an array again. However, it seems that I cannot convert all types of data to image so I need a general way to do this.

For example, lets say I have an input array of size `(2,2)`:

`input_array=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`

If I want to convert it to a `(3,3)` array, output may be like:

`output_array=np.array([[1,1,2],[1,1,2],[3,3,4]])`

Like I said before, I just don't want to tile or fill with zeros, I want to expand the size by repeating some of the elements.

Comment: Please, provide an example of the data you are dealing with and the result you want to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I don't know the result because there is not only one answer to this problem, that's why I am looking for the most efficient one. For example, lets say I have an input array of size (2,2) `input_array=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])` If I want to convert it to a (3,3) array, output may be like `output_array=np.array([[1,1,2],[1,1,2],[3,3,4]])`. Like I said before, I just don't want to tile or fill with zeros, I want to expand the size by repeating some of the elements.

Comment: If you want to repeat pre-existing data points rather than interpolate, just use **NEAREST NEIGHBOUR** resampling with OpenCV `resize()` or PIL/Pillow `resize()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a clear idea about the final result you would like to achieve, your question opens multiple paths and solutions. Just to name a few:

1. Using [`numpy.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html):

```
import numpy as np

input_array=np.array([[1.,2],[3,4]])

np.resize(input_array, (3,3))
```

you get:

```
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 1., 2.],
       [3., 4., 1.]])
```

2. Using [`cv2.resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

input_array=np.array([[1.,2],[3,4]])

cv2.resize(input_array,
           (3,3),
           interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

you get:

```
array([[1., 1., 2.],
       [1., 1., 2.],
       [3., 3., 4.]])
```

Depending on your objective, you can use different interpolation methods.

Comment: Thank you, what I was looking for was similar to second solution of yours. Since my data type can be complex numbers in some cases, I made some arrangements before resizing and now it seems working.

Answer (score 3):

If you look for pure numpy solution then you can try to use fancy indexing:

```
outshape = 3,3
rows = np.linspace(0, input_array.shape[0], endpoint=False, num=outshape[0], dtype=int)
cols = np.linspace(0, input_array.shape[1], endpoint=False, num=outshape[1], dtype=int)
# Extract result using compute indices
output_array=input_array[rows,:][:,cols]
```

Comment: Using ```resize``` from OpenCV with nearest neighbour interpolation is probably the most efficient solution because OpenCV is heavily optimized for this task. However, this way you introduce a new dependency in your project

Comment: Thank you, it seems that both numpy solution and OpenCv solution are working.